# rubyXL with dates - spec works, actual use doesn't

Tags: ruby, excel, rspec, rubyxl

Using rubyXL to handle xlsx files with dates. The spec for date handling passes, but when I try to replicate it in my own script, it doesn't work. Instead, it leaves the dates as floats/numbers (which is how dates are stored in excel). I downloaded the [rubyXL source from Github](https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL/) and ran the spec. Everything related to dates passed. However, when I run the following outside of a spec file, it exhibits the wrong behavior.

```
require 'rubyXL'

workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
worksheet = RubyXL::Worksheet.new(workbook)
workbook.worksheets << worksheet

worksheet.add_cell(0, 0, "0:0")
cell = worksheet[0][0]

date = Date.parse("January 20, 2011")
cell.change_contents(date)

puts cell.is_date? # false -- spec says it should be true
puts cell.value == date # false -- spec says it should be true
puts date # 2011-01-20
puts cell.value # 40563/1 <-- should be a date object
```

Compare this to the [rubyXL spec test](https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL/blob/master/spec/lib/cell_spec.rb) (cell starts out exactly the same as I've put it above):

```
it 'should return the value of a date' do
      date = Date.parse('January 1, 2011')
      @cell.change_contents(date)
      @cell.should_receive(:is_date?).any_number_of_times.and_return(true)
      @cell.value.should == date
    end
```

I even added some `puts` statements to check that it's actually working -- it is (outputs `2011-01-01`-like things). I also tried deleting every other file in the spec folder except for `cell_spec.rb`, just to see if there was a setting being set that I was missing. Still didn't change anything.

At this point, I'm baffled but I'm sure I must be missing something simple. I just don't get why I can't replicate the spec behavior in regular code.

Comment: I forked RubyXL and attempted to get this working; the code is a mess. I since discovered **Axlsx**, a much better gem.

Comment: @benzado I agree that `Axslx` is a better alternative for *generation*--it looked really nice. I was looking for something to *read* .xlsx files (e.g. to allow for uploaded user input, etc) and I didn't see where Axlsx would allow you to do that.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I was experiencing the same trouble simply trying to generate a file with a date in it (per your example code), hence my perspective. Good luck to you.

Comment: @benzado it's useful to mention that alternative for internet searchers, etc! :)

Answer (score 0):

The value is actually a epoc, try using `Time.at(cell.value)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).